# Script added to sudoers.d is not executed as root

Tags: php, linux, sudo, sudoers

On an xubuntu box, I have the following script to have PHP create directories owned by my user:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_REQUEST['path'])) die('No path specified');
$path = $_REQUEST['path'];
$res1 = shell_exec("sudo mkdir -p $path");
$res2 = shell_exec("sudo chown -R majid:majid $path");
var_dump($res1, $res2);
?>
```

The script is in `/var/www/path/to/mkdir.php`

I have also added this file to `/etc/sudoers.d/grantmkdir` with the following content:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/path/to/mkdir.php
```

I have `chmod`ed the file to `0440` as well. Accessing the mkdir.php from the browser, the output is `NULL NULL` for the var dumps and no directory gets created. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added permission to run those mkdir and chown commands through sudo as well? To me it seems that you are running your PHP-script without sudo, then try to run commands with sudo inside it. That is not how it works, either run mkdir.php with sudo (and then sudo inside it is redundant) or grant www-data permission to run mkdir/chown (bad idea when it comes to system security).

Comment: @SamiLaine I don't have a clear picture of what things happen here. My assumption is accessing the script with a web browser (on localhost), causes PHP to be called by Apache (who is www-data user). So the script is actually executed by www-data. This user cannot normally create the directory I specify with `$path`, but it should be able to do so if s/he (the user) issued a sudo command, which it does. So that it could execute the command without being asked a password, we have added www-data to sudoers when executing this script. It seems it should work, but it does not.

Comment: @SamiLaine I could see this method is unlike most examples of having PHP sudo. In examples I have examined the script accessed is a shell script not a PHP source. Is that the problem? If we want to use a shell script, would we be able to feed it a path like we do with the PHP source?

Comment: Has the www-data the paths set for mkdir and chmod?

Comment: @GerdK I don't understand your question. Could you explain more?

Comment: I mean: Does the prcess find sudo, mkdir and chown in the PATH? Did you try the full path to mkdir and chown? For example: "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/mkdir -p $path"? Of course with correct paths on your system.

Comment: Have you verified that `shell_exec` has not been disabled in php.ini with the `disable_functions` option?

Comment: @FuzzyTree, that is not the case. shell_exec is not disabled and executes successfully on other lines in the same source (not included here).

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is a bit confused.

When you access this script from your browser apache starts it with the www-data user.

Sudo isn't executed. You cannot make apache to call your scripts through sudo.
You have to wrap your sensitive script into a sudo call.

For example this way:

Create two scripts. The first will be called by apache, and the second will be called by the first one through sudo.

first.php:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_REQUEST['path'])) die('No path specified');
$path = $_REQUEST['path'];
// By the way here you should verify the path! Otherwise malicious users can make your system execute whatever they want...
shell_exec("sudo /var/www/path/to/second.php " . $path);
?>
```

second.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
shell_exec("sudo mkdir -p " . $argv[1]);
shell_exec("sudo chown -R majid:majid " . $argv[1]);
?>
```

And make second.php to be executable through sudo:

/etc/sudoers.d/second

```
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/path/to/second.php
```

This way apache will start first.php which will start second.php using sudo.

You can test if sudo settings are working fine with logging into your server, switch to www-data (su www-data). And run the script manually.

A few side notes:

- Checking the error logs will be probably useful. (tail /var/log/apache/error_log or stg similar)
- Don't forget to validate your input, otherwise your system will be vulnerable. Details and solution to this problem: http://php.net/escapeshellarg
- The NULL NULL can be normal. Details: http://php.net/shell_exec

> Note:
>
> ```
> This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution
> ```
>
> failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the
>   program exit code is required.

Comment: Shouldn't we then have `shell_exec("sudo php /var/www/path/to/second.php " . $path);` in the first script? And is it not possible to make the second script a shell script (`.sh`) and still pass the `path` to it?

Comment: Yes for both. It is possible to call it through php. I added '#!/usr/bin/php' to the first line which should tell sudo to run the script through php. But it is also possible to create a shell script instead. (Maybe this is easier.)

Comment: I haven't tested this yet. Will mark as the accept answer when it is tested and found to work.